# Adding mediaplayer release() crashes the app

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio and am trying to make an app that plays an audio file when a button is pressed. However, when i press the button the audio file does not play.

Also, I noticed that the OnCompletionListener part makes the app crash.

My code is as follow:

```
Button bt_moula;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.moulaga);
    bt_moula= findViewById(R.id.bt_moula);

    bt_moula.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try{
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bt_moula.setText("moulus");
        }
    });

   mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is it a null pointer exception? If so, you don't need to call release.

Comment: I changed release() to stop() but the app still crashes on launch.

Answer (score 0):

After you call release(), the object is no longer available.
release () -> release the resource in use, then allow other processes to use the file you are using.
If you want stop recording use stop().
If you want to use release(), first call stop().

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `mp` twice.

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.moulaga);
```

and

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.release();
}
```

Try renaming one of them so they don't conflict.

```
Button bt_moula;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.moulaga);
  bt_moula= findViewById(R.id.bt_moula);

  bt_moula.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try{
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bt_moula.setText("moulus");
    }
});

player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        player.release();
    }
});
}
```

If problems persist, try removing the `final` from the MediaPlayer declaration.